# Media Query not taken in account until I added !important, Possible causes?

Tags: html, css, frontend, css-grid

I spend the last 20 minutes to try to change the grid on my page but i was not able to switch from a `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr)` to a `grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr)`. Without the !important on the Media Query for the mobile version, it did not affect the grid template at all. I doubled checked but I do not have any doublon in my classes names or in my IDs names. I am just wondering what can cause that type of behavior? I think I already had the same issue few days ago, I just want to understand.

**mobile version without `!important`:**
[image: mobile version without !important]

**mobile version witht `!important`:**
[image: mobile version with !important]

**CSS - Desktop version**

```
#showcase .showcase-container{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height:25vh;
}
```

**CSS - Mobile version**

```
#showcase .showcase-container{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr) !important;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height:25vh;
}
```

edit:

this is what I have from the CSS inspector. How can I know what causes that override?

[image: CSS inspector output]

Comment: Take a look in the CSS inspector in Chrome or another browser. It will show you which rule has overridden your settings.

Comment: Thank you! Just did that, this is a very interesting tool, thank you! I saw it has been overwritten by something but how do I know from what?

Comment: Do you have something like Bootstrap?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: If you scroll up in your dev tools you can see which CSS is getting applied. Look for `display: grid` which is not strike through, this is getting applied.

Comment: Seeing that all the css properties are getting overridden in your case for mobile, just a wild guess: You sure your desktop CSS is not overriding the mobile CSS?